# Find first 'True' value in blocks in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, where one column contains only True or False values in blocks. For example:

```
df =   
            b
  0     False
  1      True
  2      True
  3     False
  4      True
  5      True
  6      True
  7      True
  8     False
  9     False
 10     False
 11     False
 12     False
 13      True
 14      True
 15      True
```

I need to find the beginning of block with True:

```
>> find_first_true(df)
>> array([1, 4, 13])
```

Any elegant solutions?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the proposed solution. I am wondering, what's the easiest way to extract blocks of a certain length, starting from the indices I found?

For example, I need to take blocks (number of rows) of length 4 before the indices. So, if my indices (found previously)

```
index = array([1, 4, 13])
```

then I need blocks:

```
[df.loc[0:4], df.loc[9:13]]
```

or

```
            b
  0     False
  1      True
  2      True
  3     False
  4      True
  9     False
 10     False
 11     False
 12     False
 13      True
```

I am looping over indices, but wonder about more pandasian solution

Comment: @MedAli, there are blocks of True and False values (as presented in the example). I need to find an index of the first True in blocks of True values. Or, if you like, first True right after False

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [2]: df = pd.read_clipboard()
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
        b
0   False
1    True
2    True
3   False
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
8   False
9   False
10  False
11  False
12  False
13   True
14   True
15   True
In [11]: np.where(((df.b != df.b.shift(1)) & df.b).values)[0]
Out[11]: array([ 1,  4, 13], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Damn, that is pretty slick.

Comment: I used `.diff()[1:]` instead of `.shift[1]`. Worked nicely

Comment: however, I'm missing the very first value. Any thought how to pick it?

Comment: @ArnoldKlein It won't miss the very first value.

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_first_true(df):
    #finds indexes of true elements
    a = list(map(lambda e: e[0] + 1 if e[1] else 0, enumerate(df))) 
    a = list(filter(bool, a))
    a = list(map(lambda x: x - 1, a))

    #removes consecutive elements   
    ta = [a[0]] + list(filter(lambda x: a[x] - a[x-1] != 1, range(1, len(a))))  
    a = list(map(lambda x: a[x], ta))   

    return a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find_first = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if (df.loc[i, 'b'] == False and df.loc[i+1, 'b'] == True):
        find_first.append(i+1)
```